# When discussing the avoida of the 'bchoros', first-born, is the correct term 'bchoros' or 'bchorim'?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, bechor-firstborn, temple-service-avoda

I think I've seen it written as 'bchoros' but since they are male shouldn't it be 'bchorim'?

Comment: https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._David_Zvi_Hoffmann/Bereshit/4.4#m7e3n6

Comment: Not sure what's grammatically correct, but certainly _b'choros_ is the more common word, colloquially, when discussing _makas b'choros_ and _taanis b'choros_.

Comment: I've seen it written both ways in classical sources.